# Autoclick the firefox popup and save files to different folder

Tags: javascript

I have a page with lots of pdf links. I want to download all those pdfs into one folder. I am trying to do this with javascript on the console. The problem with the links is that they don't have either class or id. One solution to this is looking at all the links in the document.I tried doing this:

```
for(var i = 0, len = document.links.length; i < len; i += 1) {
if(document.links[i].textContent === "*.pdf") {
    document.links[i].click();
}
}
```

But it doesn't work.
I want to click all the links of the form *.pdf. Is there something to do that in javascript.
And I tried clicking on one of the specific links. It popped up a window giving me options for saving it or opening it with pdf viewer. Is it possible to do auto-click on save button in that pop-up? Also is it possible to save the pdfs in a location different from default download directory by using javascript?

Comment: no it is not possible with javascript to auto click the save dialog that would be a security issue, you could look into using the Filesystem API but its not fully implemented.

Comment: Why don't you use wget or curl ?

Comment: @PatrickEvans Okay! But is it possible to write a regex sort-of thing in javascript which ,in this instance, will find all the links of the form *.pdf and click them?

Comment: [document.getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName), or [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector), or [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll)

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName` is use to access a element existing in the html page not a dialog or pop up that is shown by a browser

Comment: @Manish, no one said those were for doing anything with the dialog. He is wanting to get all the link elements, in order to get those he has to use some dom function, which is why i listed those 3 functions.

Comment: @evans in that case you are correct

Comment: but i forgot you can get the page links through document.links so that point is mute. @user3286661 a simple regex to use would be `/\.pdf$/` and use it against the href property not the textContent,

Answer (score 0):

`Is it possible to do auto-click on save button in that pop-up?`

No, its not possible from JS. Its browser specific feature

`It popped up a window giving me options for saving it or opening it with pdf viewer.......Also is it possible to save the pdfs in a location different from default download directory by using javascript?`

NO, The dialog that ask for save location is browser specific feature

Your JS code has no access out of your web pages.